# Как поменять стиль элемента по определённому условию?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

Мне нужно по клику на кнопку перекрасить соседний див в синий цвет. Компонент кнопка, и компонент див находятся на одном уровне.

```
<App>
<ComponentButton onClick = {..} />
<ConmponentDiv color = {..}/>
</App
```

Как правильно создать action который вызывает клик, а также в редаксе хранить цвет, который я передаю в  ConmponentDiv? Использую стэк react/typescript/redux.

компонент div:

```
const ComponentDiv = () => {
    const style = {
        color: "blue"
    }

    return (

        <div style={style}>
            hello
        </div>

    )
}

export default ComponentDiv;
```

компонент для кнопки:

```
const ComponentButton = () => {
    return (
            <button
                onClick={...}
                className="btn">click me
            </button>
    );
};

export default ComponentButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Значение цвета должно храниться как часть состояния ридакса. После нажатия на кнопку вызывается  dispatch с экшеном изменения цвета. После получения из редьюсера нового состояния компонент дива перерисуется и изменит цвет.

Comment: Как все сложно... В vue можно сделпть очень просто через директивы или назначением класса по условию